# Android Studio error "android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class " when trying to use GeckoView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library, gecko

So, I'm trying to use GeckoView in my Android app. When I run my app I get this error:

```
"Process: com.example.planetarium_3d, PID: 1586
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity   
ComponentInfo{com.example.planetarium_3d/com.example.planetarium_3d.Fullscree     nActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class org.mozilla.gecko.GeckoView"
```

I've placed the .jar files in my **libs** folder  - !https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6EvX.png

This is my code: http://pastebin.com/kGCjfuAC

This is my activity xml file: http://pastebin.com/s8GYnucS

And this is error log: http://pastebin.com/2yXR6imZ

How can I resolve this issue ?

Comment: Hi, i have posted an aswer, tell me if it works :)

Comment: The path has changed, this will happen if you do `.gecko.GeckoView` and not `org.mozilla.geckoview.GeckoView`

Answer (score 1):

Exception:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error
>   inflating class org.mozilla.gecko.GeckoView"

Inside your Activity xml file, you dont need `class = "org.mozilla.gecko"`:

```
  <org.mozilla.gecko.GeckoView
       android:id="@+id/geckoViewObj"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"

       />
```